# how to get access the parameter inside do-while loop in c#

Tags: c#

I have following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[][] Period = new int[4][]
        {
            new int[]{1,4,2,5,6},
            new int[]{1,2,3,4,7,5},
            new int[]{2,3,4},
            new int[]{1,3,2,5,7},
        };

        do
        {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 3;

            int[] row1 = Period[a];
            int[] row2 = Period[b];

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int a1 = rnd.Next(0, row1.Length);
            int a2 = rnd.Next(0, row2.Length);

            int b1 = row1[a1];
            int b2 = row2[a2];

        } while ();

        int temp = b1;
        b1 = b2;
        b2 = temp;

        row1[a1] = b1;
        row2[a2] = b2;


        Period[a] = row1;
        Period[b] = row2;

        for (int i = 0; i < Period.Length; i++)
        {
            int[] innerArray = Period[i];
            for (int x = 0; x < innerArray.Length; x++)
            {
                Console.Write(innerArray[x] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


    }
```

I want to access the parameter inside the do-while loop for example b1,b2, row1 ,... So how can I access to them in order to use them after while loop?

Secondly I want to coded the while as follow:

```
  while (row1.contains(b2) || row2.contains(b1));
```

as you can see because all the data are inside do-while loop I couldn't access them, do you have any suggestion? 
Thanks

Comment: Declare the variables static and make them public...

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in a single post. It doesn't help that you've posted code that wouldn't compile at the moment - and it's not clear what you mean by "the parameter"... your question needs a fair amount of work to be clear.

Comment: @ryekayo: That's almost *always* a bad idea, and there's no indication it's useful here, given that all the code we've seen is in a single method.

Comment: Thanks for that info Jon, that's the only idea I could think of...

Comment: @HesamE word of advice it's better to write your code and break it into multiple functions and or procedures rather than trying to execute all the code in a single method especially the main please do some research in your spare time on `C# coding basics for beginners` thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So how can I access to them in order to use them after while loop?

You have to declare them outside of the scope of the `while` loop, to the parent scope. For instance, let's take the `b1`:

```
int b1;
do
{

}while();
```

For a detailed discussion about scopes, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: b1 will be produced inside the do-while loop, and then I want to use it out side the loop, I did your proposed but it gives these error: A local variable named 'b1' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'b1', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: don't redeclare it inside the loop. you will also have to initialize it outside the loop. `int b1 = 0;` then inside your do/while `b1 = row1[a1]`. now, b1 will only be the last value it was set to inside your loop. This will also let you test b1 and b2.

Comment: @HesamE You don't have to re-declare it inside the `while` loop. Actually, this is impossible, due to the error message you got, which is pretty detailed. You have to declare it outside the `while` once and then you can access it to the scope of `while` as also to scope you have declared this variable, outside the `while`.